# What is Block meaning in Magento?

Tags: magento

I cant understand the meaning of,

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

What is meaning of `type="catalog/product_list"` ? Which file its denote?

Please Explain me?

I am try.

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block` ,inside i cant find Product list file. Anything wrong in my search?Sorry for my silly question am new to magento.

[Manage Category Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVmlH.png)

[image: Home page Cms]

[Cms page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXheU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Navigate to => app/code/core/Mage/catalog/Block/Product/List.php
```

And you will see a class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`, so the block `type="catalog/product_list"` is referencing to this block class and links the tempate.

**update**
It links your template to that particular block. if you go see at template ="catalog/product/list.phtml" (i.e. `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`) you will see the the methods of this block being called.

Also, on `list.phtml` file `echo get_class($this)`. you will see the same block class being printed.

Would you try this on `Layout Update XML` of your homepage

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" as="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>2</value></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: type="catalog/product_list", ok in the list .php which function its call? How template="catalog/product/list.phtml" load this template?where template file located.

Comment: {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} in this cant loading template when copy the above coding in cms->home page->content.

Comment: are you sure your category with `id 2` contains products and are visible with stock and everything else, i mean to say valid products ?

Comment: Yes having product,visible and in stock status only,when click subcategory menu it showing product but in home page its not showing.

Comment: are you fetching multiple type of product with same kinda cms code ? `{{block type="" }}` please do update your anwer with what is there in content

Comment: {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} in my content like these,in category id 2 having two products and also subcategory having same two product.

Comment: Actually in magento by default category id 2 id of `Default Category`, have you rechecked on it ? `catalog > Manage Categories > Click on category name to see cat id along with category name`

Comment: Yes in default category only i have 2 products.

Comment: You aren't shwing your content so, i couldn't help you. sometime if the name of two cms blocks are same, you don't get the result. you need to change name in that case.

Comment: Plz refer my image attachment above.

Comment: are you see above image?is it enough to see my content.

Comment: Great,Thank you so much finally i got output.

Comment: Once i want show all product means how to write Layout Update XML ?

Comment: Remove the action block part that has set category id, else would get you all products.